# Mounting box slightly offset in ceiling: is there an offset mounting bracket that I can use to mount ceiling fan?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, mounting, junction-box

We're having a new house built, and yesterday we went to check out the progress. They've finished drywalling and sheetrock mudding and we noticed that the electrician installed one box off center. We've already had a very long back and forth with the electrician and the builder over numerous issues, so we're trying to limit our complaints at this time. Is there some sort of a bracket I can buy and mount a flush mount ceiling fan off center to cover this up?

Another thought we had was to maybe rather than a ceiling fan, get some type of a wide light fixture and mount it off center.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

[image: ceiling]

Comment: This box should be in the center of the width of the room. It is not lined up with the other one beyond. Unless there is something about the room not shown in the picture (e.g., an alcove in the left wall or an opening to another room), this box is in the wrong place. There is no good way to deal with this other than moving it now before the ceiling is textured.

Comment: It's definitely in the wrong place - dealing with this particular electrician has been an absolute nightmare. At this point, the builder is pretty annoyed with us because we keep calling out mistakes, so we are trying to limit our complaints and really just wanted to see if there was something creative we could do here. We were thinking possibly using some geometric light fixture or something might hide the fact that it's off center, but nothing we came up with seemed ideal, other than simply asking them to move it.

Comment: Wait for comments from experts here to gain a full understanding of whether the location of this box is acceptable or not.

Comment: @cloudwalker the builder should be catching the mistakes before you do.  Keep calling them out.  Don’t let mistakes go uncorrected.

Comment: It looks off set I agree, however we cannot see if there is any structure above that required the shift.what I do see is that it looks to be attached to the joist, I am not sure why it is not centered like the one on the far end of the photo unless there there was structure in that locarion, but shifts in lighting like this make it look like low quality work. If there is nothing in the way it should be able to be shifted on the same joists.

Comment: Is there plumbing or a beam above the offset location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks off set I agree, however we cannot see if there is any structure above that required the shift.what I do see is that it looks to be attached to the joist, I am not sure why it is not centered like the one on the far end of the photo unless there there was structure in that locarion, but shifts in lighting like this make it look like low quality work. If there is nothing in the way it should be able to be shifted on the same joists.

Comment: Yeah, I think they simply mounted it on the other side of the joist for some reason. Is there something we can do, like a bracket or something, that we can mount the light to, or do we simply need to ask them to move it?

Comment: Look at the nail or screw lines the joists run left to right in the photo that's why I was guessing there was something in the way.

Comment: We're going over there today, so I'll take a look. I'll also ask them why they did not centered it and see if they can just fix it now. Thanks for the info!